# How to create a date generator in shell?

Tags: shell, powershell, date, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to pull some information from a website from past 4 years and each file is date based, like `http://ransompull.com/pullme/2013-04-06/example.2013-04-06.txt`

and it is the starting file and it ends today, so i want to pull all the txt files from last 4 years.

What I tried:

```
DATE=`date +%Y`
MONTH='01'
DAY='1'
for i in range(1,31);
for j in range(01,12):
do wget http://ransompull.com/pullme/$DATE$i/example.$DATE$i.txt;
done
done
```

But this seems to wrong as iterating over month and date is not feasible as it is not giving desired output.Any suggestions on how to pull all data from

`http://ransompull.com/pullme/2013-04-06/example.2013-04-06.txt`
to 
`http://ransompull.com/pullme/2017-08-10/example.2017-08-10.txt`

Comment: Your code looks like bash, but you've also included the batch and PowerShell tags. What language are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of counting years, months and days,
you could just count days relative to the start date.
If you have the GNU implementation of the `date` command,
you can use it to compute the relative date, for example:

```
date +%F -d '2013-04-06 + 1000 days'
```

This outputs `2016-01-01`.
You can create a loop, generating dates by incrementing the number of days from start, until you reach the end:

```
start=2013-04-06
end=2017-08-10
date=$start
days=0

while [ "$date" != "$end" ]; do
    date=$(date +%F -d "$start + $days days")
    wget http://ransompull.com/pullme/$date/example.$date.txt
    ((days++))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$startdate=get-date 2017-08-11
$enddate=$startdate.AddYears(-4)

0..($startdate - $enddate).Days | %{wget ("http://ransompull.com/pullme/{0:yyyy-MM-dd}/example.{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" -f $startdate.AddDays(-$_))}
```